# Semantic Media Wiki Categories for Templates

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

We are running MediaWiki 1.34.2 with SMW 3.2.0 and want to query (ask) for all templates of a certain Category. The category is shown on the template page and the template is shown on the category page. But when using Special Page Browse wiki, the category is not shown. When printing the response of the query, the list is not complete and no template has a category. We added the required namespaces and tried to rebuild the wiki.

Template:

```
<noinclude>
[[Category:Test]]
<pre>
{{Device
|Name=
}}
</pre>
</noinclude>
<includeonly>
{| class="wikitable"
! Name
| {{{Name|}}}
|}
[[Category:TestInt]]
</includeonly>
```

Ask:

```
{{#ask:
[[Template:+]] | ?Category
}}
```

Comment: Did you try to run job queue?

Comment: Yes, the job queue is empty.

Comment: Could you provide some details: ask query, template content. I'm pretty sure your problem is here.

Comment: I have added it to the problem description.

Comment: Looks ok... Double check that you correctly set the namespace (should be 10). Also, try to edit/save your templates pages.

Comment: The namespace is set correctly and edit/save does not help.

Comment: Does "Modification date" property appears when browsing?

Comment: I hope you have enabled semantics for templates (https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:$smwgNamespacesWithSemanticLinks)?

Answer (score 1):

To ask for templates in a certain category, you need to ask for the category like

```
{{#ask:
[[Template:+]][[Category:Some Category Name]]
}}
```

See also https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries